# jQUery UI Dialog - can it work like iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a dialog that has form in it and when the form is submitted it is going to submit location, how can I ensure that my Dialog is working like iFrame so that my browser location will stay like it is, only Dialog will open new form location?

Comment: @dotoree nah, if it opens different site and someone clicks link in it it will still redirect my browser there

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to put an actual iframe in your dialog.  But be aware that the target site can still use window.top to "break out" of your frame and take control of the whole window.

Comment: @Qmal Then I think only with Iframe

Comment: you can ajax submit form and send back html from action url and put that in dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `<iframe id=herpaderp></iframe>` in the dialog, and set property `target=herpaderp` on the `form`.

This will cause the form's `POST` result to be loaded in the `iframe`.

If the form is also inside the dialog, you need to add logic to the `submit` button to hide the form during submitting.

---

/!\  Note for IE8 - when I tried this, it had trouble printing from inside the `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form using ajax and show the response in your dialog,

Then you can bind the click for a elements in the external page in order to prevent redirection. if you still want to follow the link you can do another ajax request to the link clicked and show the response in your dialog.

```
//you might need to edit the selector 
$('#mydialog a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //here you need to perform a ajax request to $(this).attr("href")
    //and show the response in #mydialog again
})
```

hope this helps,